# How can i get height 100% of sidebar block?

Tags: html, css

I have this html markup:

```
...
    <div style="background-color: #bcceb4; width: 300px;">
        <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; float: left;">1</div>
        <div style="background-color: yellowgreen; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left;">3</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
...
```

[image: Here is a screenshot]

I need the yellow block to fill the entire space. Height 100% and inheritance are not working!

Answer (score 1):

Set height main div to for example 200px and both div set to 100% height

```
<div style="background-color: #bcceb4; width: 300px;height:200px">
<div style="display:inline-block; background-color: yellow; width: 100px;float: left;height:100%;">1</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; background-color: yellowgreen; width: 200px; float: left;height:100%;">3</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Try this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6yu4W/)

Comment: I dont know main tag height, because it will depends on the height of the yellowgreen block and its dinamic content

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of yellow block to `100%`? Like in:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UM54g/)

Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, i need to fill it in vertical, not in horizont.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` and set there the height:

**html**

```
<div style="background-color: #bcceb4; width: 300px;">
        <div class="yellowCont" style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px;float:left;">1</div>
        <div style="background-color: yellowgreen; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left;">3</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.yellowCont:after{
    content: "";
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;    
    height:175px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G97rL/)

Answer (score 0):

When you specify 100% or inherit, it needs to refer to the parents height, if you add 100% just to the yellow div, it will be 100% of its parent, for which you didn't specify the ehgith

Add inherit or 100% height to the parent and all the levels between the main one and the yellow one.

Example:

```
div id="main" style="height:300px";> // your dynamic div
    <div style="background-color: #bcceb4;height:inherit">
        <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 100px; float: left;height:100%;">1</div>
        <div style="background-color: yellowgreen; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left;">3</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5SZ8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS styling is not inherently 100%. It is inherently auto, meaning only the space that is needed. You have to tell it height:100% other wise it will default to enough space for the text plus the default padding.